# VBA Excel and Putty (FTP) - Wait Call Shell and bypass host key is not cached in the registry

Tags: excel, vba, ftp, putty

I have a macro in my excel file that uploads a file to my server using the pscp (putty client).

This is the code

```
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

Dim cstrSftp As String
Dim strCommand As String
Dim pUser As String
Dim pPass As String
Dim pHost As String
Dim pFile As String
Dim pRemotePath As String

'Specifying the values
cstrSftp = """" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\pscp.exe" & """"
pUser = "username"
pPass = "password  "
pHost = "ftp.xyz.com"
pFile = """" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\test.mkv" & """"
pRemotePath = "/home/storage/public_html/"

'Setting the command
strCommand = cstrSftp & " -sftp -l " & pUser & " -pw " & pPass & _
    " " & pFile & " " & pHost & ":" & pRemotePath

'Execution
 wsh.Run strCommand, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```

This works fine, but i have two problems:

1) Using Windows 10 the system popup a message asking to the user if he wants to run the pscp.exe. I would like to bypass that.

Instead of WScript.Shell i was using this:

```
Call Shell(strCommand, vbNormalFocus)
```

Using Call Shell the operation system don't ask about running the pscp.exe, but the problem is i don't have a way to know when the process is over

2) When the user runs the command for the first time, putty prompt this message:

> The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You have no
>   guarantee  that the server is the computer you think it is. The
>   server's rsa2 key > fingerprint is: [ssh-rsa 1024 somekey] If you
>   trust this host, enter "y" to add   the key to PuTTY's cache and carry
>   on connecting. If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
>   adding the key to the cache, enter "n". If you do not trust this host,
>   press Return to abandon the connection. Store key in cache? (y/n)

I need it to be completely prompt free, automatic.

I tried to use "echo n" like this:

strCommand = "echo n | " & cstrSftp & " -sftp -l " & pUser & " -pw " & pPass & _
        " " & pFile & " " & pHost & ":" & pRemotePath

But i get the message that the "IWshShell3" failed.

Comment: Those are two separate questions. So ask them separately.

Answer (score -1):

Problem 2 solved!

Echo is a batch file command so it needs to have a wrapper round it.

This command works:

strCommand = "cmd /c echo n | " & cstrSftp & " -sftp -l " & pUser & " -pw " & pPass & _
        " " & pFile & " " & pHost & ":" & pRemotePath

Comment: Never do this! The prompt is there for a reason. The host key must be verified.